# Can't yank/paste register during a macro

Tags: vim

I have a file that I need to make a lot of edits to that looks something like this:

```
hello[link](#hello)

world[link](#world)
```

and I want to end up with:

```
<a name="hello"></a>
hello[[link](#hello)]

<a name="world"></a>
world[[link](#world)]
```

Right now my macro looks something like the following. After manually moving the cursor via `/link`:

`wwyt)O<a name="<Esc>pa"></a>`

It works up until I need to paste from the yank register at which point it just dies. I've also tried specifying the register with `"*y`/`"*p` with no luck. Any ideas what's going on and how I can get around it?

Comment: Apparently it was unrelated, was just able to do this. It must have failed due to something else

Comment: Ah apparently it must have to do with a custom mapping I have (using `jk` instead of `<Esc>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can try:

- Go to the very first character of the file (`gg`)
- Start recording macro (`qq`)
- `ywi<a name="`<kbd>esc</kbd>`pli"></a>`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Stop recording macro and apply to other lines

Answer (score 0):

This command will convert all non-empty lines following your rule.

```
g/./s#\v([^[]*)(.*)#<a name="\1"></a>\r\1[\2]#
```